# Github commits from different PC's

Tags: github, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

Quick question, if i have different PC's which share the same/different projects which I would like to make commits to.

How can I make sure that all the commits will be made from my GitHub account owner? Right now, it commits with the PC username instead of my GitHub account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your Git username the following way:

> 1. **Open Git Bash.**
> 2. **Set a Git username:**
>
>    `$ git config --global user.name "Mona Lisa"`
> 3. **Confirm that you have set the Git username correctly:**
>
>    `$ git config --global user.name`
>
>    Will output *Mona Lisa*

Reference: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Comment: @rivar_ If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.